# Is there anyway to control memory usage of python process?

Tags: python

Is there anyway to control memory usage of python process just like JVM process ? Thanks

Comment: Not to my knowledge, or at least, not using python tools (you could always trick the OS to kill a process if they exceed memory usage). But it would be interesting to know if I'm wrong or missing something :)

Comment: You could force garbage collection many times from within the process I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

No. Not like you can in Java. If you're running on Linux then you could use `ulimit` to limit the amount of memory allowed by processes spawned by the current one:

```
$ ulimit -Sv 1048576  # soft virtual memory limit of 1GB
$ ./yourscript.py
```